# Block "Similar Questions" box refreshment when mouse pointer hovers it

Tags: feature-request, design

...or there is `touchstart` event initiated.

Maybe I'm the only one on "Stack Exchange" planet with this problem, but it simply *drives me crazy*, when I middle click any question in either "*Similar Quetions*" or "*Questions that may already have your answer*" boxes only to find out, that **there is a completely different question** opened in another tab, because box was refreshed exactly during my middle click. I don't know, if I'm just lucky enough, but I'm pretty sure, that it happened way too much times to me.

Can we, please, have a feature, that would block refreshment of these boxes, when mouse cursor hovers any of it or there as on ongoing touch event? Please, dear developers, please, please...

Comment: *middle click*? Isn't one mouse button enough?